# Not sure why this syntax error is happening

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Hi I'm not very familiar with MySQL as I have only started using it today and I keep getting this syntax error and am not really sure what the problem is. I have attached a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtArg.png) of the code and also pasted it below with the error in bold.

I'm sorry if this is a silly error that is easily fixed I'm just not sure how to fix it and would be very appreciative of any help.

```
CREATE TABLE copy (
    `code` INT NOT NULL,
    isbn CHAR(17) NOT NULL,
    duration TINYINT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pkcopy  PRIMARY KEY (isbn, `code`),
    CONSTRAINT fkcopy FOREIGN KEY (isbn) REFERENCES book (isbn));

CREATE TABLE student (
    `no` INT NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    school CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    embargo BIT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pkstudent PRIMARY KEY (`no`));

CREATE TABLE loan (
    `code` INT NOT NULL,
    `no` INT NOT NULL,
    taken DATE NOT NULL,
    due DATE NOT NULL,
    `return` DATE NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pkloan PRIMARY KEY (taken, `code`, `no`),
    CONSTRAINT fkloan FOREIGN KEY (`code`, `no`) REFERENCES copy, student **(**`code`, `no`));
```

Comment: You cannot reference to two different tables while creating a Foreign Key (even if it is composite)

Answer (score 0):

Create the tables first, then use the ALTER TABLE statement to add the foreign keys one by one.  You won't be able to call two different tables on the foreign key, so you'll have to use an ID that maps to both.  Here is an example to add the foreign keys after the table has been created:

Add a new table named vendors and change the products table to include the vendor id field:

```
USE dbdemo;

CREATE TABLE vendors(
    vdr_id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    vdr_name varchar(255)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

ALTER TABLE products 
ADD COLUMN vdr_id int not null AFTER cat_id;
```

To add a foreign key to the products table, you use the following statement:

```
ALTER TABLE products
ADD FOREIGN KEY fk_vendor(vdr_id)
REFERENCES vendors(vdr_id)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```